# $X^3 + 22Y^3 + 3Z^3 = 0$ has no rational solution

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

This is Exercise 1.4 in Swinnerton-Dyer's *A Brief Guide to Algebraic Number Theory*.

Write $\alpha = \sqrt[3]{22}$ and $k = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. I have shown that $k$ has class number 3 and the norm form is
$$ \mathrm{norm}(a + b\alpha + c\alpha^2) = a^3 + 22b^3 + 22^2c^3 - 66abc. $$

Assuming that $(x,y,z)$ is a primitive solution of $X^3+22Y^3+3Z^3=0$ with $z > 0$, we find
$$ N(x+y\alpha) = |x^3+22y^3| = 3z^3. $$
Since $3$ is totally ramified in $k$, i.e. $3\mathcal{O}_k = \mathfrak{p}_3^3$, we can write
$$ (x+y\alpha) = \mathfrak{p}_3 \mathfrak{a}, $$
for some $\mathfrak{a}$ with $N\mathfrak{a} = z^3$.
The exercise says to show that $\mathfrak{a}$ is a cube, which would lead to a contradiciton since $\mathfrak{p}_3$ is not principal, and this is where I am having trouble.

Writing $\mathfrak{a} = \prod \mathfrak{p}^{a_{\mathfrak{p}}}$, the primes with $a_{\mathfrak{p}} \neq 0$ are above the primes dividing $z$ and I want to show that $a_{\mathfrak{p}} \equiv 0 \bmod 3$ for every $\mathfrak{p}$.
If $N\mathfrak{p} = p^{f_{\mathfrak{p}}}$, the fact that the norm of $\mathfrak{a}$ is a cube says
$$ \sum_{\mathfrak{p} \mid p} a_{\mathfrak{p}} f_{\mathfrak{p}} \equiv 0 \bmod 3.$$

If $p = 2,3$ or $11$, then $p$ is totally ramified in $k$, i.e. $p\mathcal{O}_k = \mathfrak{p}_p^3$, so $p \mid z$ implies $\mathfrak{p}_p^3 \mid \mathfrak{a}$ and the result holds.

I now consider a prime $p \neq 2,3,11$ which divides $z$.
The equation gives
$$ x^3 + 22y^3 \equiv 0 \bmod p^3, $$
and because of coprimality, we find that $22$ is a cube modulo $p$ so we cannot have $f_{\mathfrak{p}} = 3$ for any $\mathfrak{p} \mid p$. This gives $a_{\mathfrak{p}} \equiv 0 \bmod 3$ when $\mathfrak{p}$ is the only prime above $p$ dividing $\mathfrak{a}$.

The problem is that I do not see how to reach that conclusion when there are more than one prime factor of $p\mathcal{O}_k$ appearing in the decomposition of $\mathfrak{a}$. For instance, if $p\mathcal{O}_k = \mathfrak{p}_1 \mathfrak{p}_2 \mathfrak{p}_3$, why can we not have $\mathfrak{a} = \mathfrak{p}_1 \mathfrak{p}_2^2$?

Comment: Have you ever worked through a proof of a similar result, such as Selmer's equation $3x^3 + 4y^3 + 5z^3 = 0$ not having a rational solution besides $(0,0,0)$?  That is discussed at https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/selmerexample.pdf, where multiplying through by 2 converts the problem to showing there is no nontrivial rational solution to $X^3 + 6Y^3 = 10Z^3$ ($X = 2y$, $Y = x$, $Z = -z$).  The structure of $\mathbf Q(\sqrt[3]{6})$ is relevant to that solution.

Comment: @KCd Exactly what I was looking for, I read other writings on your website but somehow missed that one! This should solve my question.

Comment: You can find Selmer's equation and the one you write about as Lemma 9.1 and Lemma 9.2 of Chapter 10 in Cassels' *Local Fields*.  He gives details for the Selmer equation and is then very brief in his account of the equation $x^3 + 22y^3 + 3z^3 = 0$.

Comment: @KCd Great! If you are willing to write this as an answer, I would gladly accept it. Otherwise I will just write one myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/selmerexample.pdf) for a treatment of the similar (and more famous) equation $3x^3 + 4y^3 + 5z^3 = 0$.  This example and the one you write about are also in Chapter 10 of Cassels' *Local Fields*: see Lemma 9.1 and 9.2.

Answer (score 0):

for what it may be worth, we can also ask when the integer polynomial
$$  x^3 + 22 y^3 + 484 z^3 - 66xyz \equiv 0 \pmod p $$
has no solutions except $$x,y,z \equiv 0 \pmod p$$
which is a finite check.

That happens  for small primes

$$     13,     19,     31,     37,     61,    109, $$